# Floating figures collide

Tags: floats

I've been using \usepackage{floatflt} with \documentclass{article}

```
\begin{floatingfigure}[l]{4.5cm}    
\includegraphics[scale=0.21]{image}
\end{floatingfigure}
```

but when you use it twice or more, it says a warning message that figures 1 & 2 collide.

When I used it the third time, it doesn't show the figure. How to fix this?

---

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

 \begin{floatingfigure}[l]{4.5cm}   
\includegraphics[scale=0.21]{p1}
\end{floatingfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{floatingfigure}[r]{4.5cm}    
\includegraphics[scale=0.21]{p2}
\end{floatingfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{floatingfigure}[r]{4.5cm}    
\includegraphics[scale=0.21]{p3}
\end{floatingfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Where p1, p2 and p3 are the images.

Comment: Which package, or document class, provides an environment called `floatingfigure`? Please advise.

Comment: Main post edited.

Comment: please make a small document that shows the problem (use `example-image`) so other people have the same input

Comment: It's been edited.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of the package says

> If two consecutive paragraphs both contain a floating float, a
>   "collision warning" is issued. This warning may be ignored.